# What's the meaning of @var in php comments

Tags: php

I see this (@var) in php comments a lot and have no clue what it means. Please tell.

```
// example.php (taken from yii framework application code)

<?php
/* @var $this CategoriesController */
/* @var $data Categories */
?>

<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('idCategory')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->idCategory), array('view', 'id'=>$data->idCategory)); ?>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> You may use the @var tag to document the data type of class variables.
>
> The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc), a
> class name for the type of object, or simply "mixed". phpDocumentor
> will display the optional description unmodified, and defaults to
> "mixed" if the datatype is not present

https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html

> > With the @var tag it is possible to document the type and function of a class property. When provided it MUST contain a Type to indicate
> > what is expected; the description on the other hand is OPTIONAL yet
> > RECOMMENDED in case of complicated structures, such as associative
> > arrays.
>
> The @var tag MAY have a multi-line description and does not need
> explicit delimiting.
>
> It is RECOMMENDED when documenting to use this tag with every
> property.
>
> This tag MUST NOT occur more than once per property in a PHPDoc and is
> limited to Structural Elements of type property.

Example:

```
class DemoVar
{
   /**
    * Summary
    *
    * @var object Description
    */
   protected $varWithDescriptions;

   /**
    * @var \DemoVar $instance The class instance.
    */
   protected static $instance;

   /**
    * Summary for varWithWrongType
    *
    * @var boolean The varWithWrongType. Boolean will be put in the type.
    */
   protected $varWithWrongType = array();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

They are PHPdoc comments and are generally used for IDE-typehinting/code completion (also sometimes documentation-generation, but not in this scenario). They have no relevance on the application itself and can be removed without incident.

Comment: There are plenty...imho the best one is phpStorm (win/mac/linux) but there's also netbeans and eclipse among others

Comment: You have made my morning, my friend. I'll check them out.

Comment: for people googling today consider emacs with lsp-mode

Answer (score 5):

It is in an inline type hint.

e.g.

```
/* @var bool */
$switch
```

In this case it means `$this` is of type `CategoriesController` and `$data` is of type `Categories`

Often used by IDEs for type hinting.

Answer (score 0):

That is `phpdoc`, to make automated documentation:

[phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

Answer (score -1):

This is how it needs to be specified for arrays:

```
/**
 * @var MyDto[]
 */
```